# Represent an Integral by non-elementary functions

Tags: calculus, integration

I would like to ask everyone about the following integral:
$$
I = \int_0^\infty  {\frac{{\sqrt {{x^2} + ax + b} }}{x}{e^{\mu x}}dx} 
$$
where a,b, and $\mu$ are constants. The equation $x^2+ax+b=0$ doesn't have a root.
How to represent the above integral by non-elementary functions? Since I know it is impossible to represent it by elementary functions.

Comment: Doesn't it diverge for $b \neq 0$?

Answer (score 2):

As @sos440 notes, the integral diverges unless $b = 0$; it also diverges unless $\Re{\mu} <0$.  So let's write the integral as

$$\int_0^{\infty} \sqrt{1+\frac{a}{x}} e^{-s x}$$

where $\Re{s} > 0$.

This is a difficult integral to evaluate.  The best I could do is express it in terms of a confluent hypergeometric function of the 2nd kind:

$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi } U\left(-\frac{1}{2},0,a s\right)}{s}$$

where

$$U\left(-\frac{1}{2},0,a s\right) = -\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^{\infty} dt \: e^{-a s t} \, t^{-3/2} (1+t)^{-1/2}$$

Comment: "confluent hypergeometric function of the 2nd kind" - or the "Tricomi confluent hypergeometric function" to other people. :) Laplace transforms are fun!

Comment: @J.M.: If I were Mr. Tricomi, I'd be a bit peeved that most people use the letter $U$ to represent my function and not $T$.

Comment: He actually used $\Psi(a,b,z)$ as the notation in his book, if memory serves. I believe some papers to this day persist on using that notation, tho of course $U$ is now what they use in most computing environments.

Comment: So what if b≠0 and μ<0? Does that integral diverge?

Comment: Yes it does, because the integrand behaves as $1/x$ at $x=0$, which is a non-integrable singularity (blows up as $\log{x}$).